# Compare two list of objects a in C# and retrieve another list with un match records

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've two lists of objects I need to compare these two lists and get results with unmatched records.

```
var oldlist = new List<Employee>{
new Employee(){EmployeeID=123,Name="XXXX",Gender="Male",code="CSE"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=231,Name="FFF",Gender="Male",code="EC"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=431,Name="GGG",Gender="Female",code="IT"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=543,Name="DDD",Gender="Female",code="IT"}
}
var newlist = new List<Employee>{
new Employee(){EmployeeID=123,Name="HHH",Gender="Male",code="IT"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=231,Name="JJJ",Gender="FeMale",code="CSE"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=431,Name="GGG",Gender="Female",code="IT"},
new Employee(){EmployeeID=543,Name="DDD",Gender="Female",code="IT"}
}
```

In the above code, EmployeeId will be the same but there will be changes in any other values like
for EmployeeId 123 and 231 their values are changed I need to get only the unmatched records in the above example result should give only records with employeeId 123 and 231 because the remaining records are unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `list1.except(list2)`  to find the set difference between two lists: [-find-the-set-difference-between-two-lists-linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-the-set-difference-between-two-lists-linq)

```
 var result= oldlist.Except(newlist).ToList();
```

**edit:**

You can use the following method to compare two lists of objects:

```
        List<Employee> list=new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var item in oldlist)
        {
            if(!newlist.Any(p=>p.EmployeeID==item.EmployeeID && p.Name == item.Name && p.Gender == item.Gender && p.code == item.code))
               list.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: I've tried this it working for list<string> not working for objects

Comment: Your code example is a List of Employees, not objects.

Comment: @Ramu try to use my code

Comment: This is totally wrong!. The example given in the link above works on strings or other value types. It cannot work on reference types. You need an instance of a class that implements an IComparer<Employee> to establish if two instances of a reference types _contains_ different data. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-7.0